Angular Light/Dark Mode Switcher Reloads Entire Page When Clicking
I'm working on an Angular application with a light/dark mode switcher. The switcher is supposed to toggle between light and dark mode and also change the logo (which is an SVG image) accordingly. However, when I click on the switcher, it appears as though the entire page reloads.
Clicking on the theme switcher causes the whole page to refresh or reload.
I have a StackBlitz demo where I've tried to implement this, but I couldn't manage to include the SVG images properly.
What I need help with:

Understanding why clicking the switcher might cause the page to reload.
Correct way to handle SVG images and switch them dynamically without causing a page reload.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Stackblitz Demo
main.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
  @if (this.counter%2) {
      <img src="light.svg" alt="light-logo">

    } @else {
      <img src="dark.svg" alt="dark-logo">
    }
    <button type="button" (click)="changeTheme()">Change Theme</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  counter = 0;

  public changeTheme() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}


Is there a <form> element anywhere in the button's hierarchy? The browser could be assuming that it's the submit button and refreshing the page when the button is clicked because the form was submitted.

NOTE: Related to add in stackblitz a .svg: 1.-create a folder "assets" inside folder "src", 2.-change the angular.json adding in projects-->[your-project]-->architect-->build-->options-->assets: ["src/assets"], 3.-use, e.g. <img src="assets/dark.svg" alt="dark-logo"> 4.-save and 5.-reload the page.

The page does not reload, you can check this by putting a console.log on ngOnInit, you will notice it's only called once on load. For the ugly transition you can use Angular animations to make the transition a bit more pleasing.
trigger('fadeInOut', [
  transition(':enter', [
    // :enter is alias to 'void => *'
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate(500, style({ opacity: 1 })),
  ]),
  // transition(':leave', [   // :leave is alias to '* => void'
  //   animate(500, style({opacity:0}))
  // ])
]),

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { trigger, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        // :enter is alias to 'void => *'
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(500, style({ opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      // transition(':leave', [   // :leave is alias to '* => void'
      //   animate(500, style({opacity:0}))
      // ])
    ]),
  ],
  imports: [],
  template: `
  @if (this.counter%2) {
      <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg" alt="light-logo"  [@fadeInOut]>

    } @else {
      <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/acid.svg" alt="dark-logo"  [@fadeInOut]>
    }
    <button type="button" (click)="changeTheme()">Change Theme</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  counter = 0;

  public changeTheme() {
    this.counter++;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('asdf');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));

Stackblitz Demo
